# How do I save a Bitmap to a file?

Tags: c#, image, file, bitmap, save

I'm making a small paint program and I want users to be able to save their creations to a file. But whenever I try to save something, it results in "System.NullReferenceException". Also, how do I make an option for the user to choose in what format to save in? Cheers.

Code used to save:

```
private void opslaan(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Schets schets;
    SaveFileDialog fileOpslaan = new SaveFileDialog();

    fileOpslaan.Title = "Bestand opslaan";
    fileOpslaan.AddExtension = true;
    fileOpslaan.Filter = "Bitmap Afbeelding (*.bmp)|*.bmp|JPEG Afbeelding (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|GIF Afbeelding (*.gif)|*.gif|PNG Afbeelding (*.png)|*.png";

    if (fileOpslaan.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            schets.bitmap.Save(fileOpslaan.FileName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `schets` is null when you call `schets.bitmap.Save(fileOpslaan.FileName);`.

Comment: Seems like you dont instantiate `schets`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Schets schets = ... //Say here what your schets is, otherwise it's null.
```